# Inverted Colors after Imagemagick Upgrade from 6.9 to 7

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm using Imagick and the PHP Imagick extension in a project to convert all sorts of images. The images are given from users and will be converted to jpg thumbnails of a given size.

This is running inside a docker-container based on `php:7.4.12-cli`. Currently I'm using `Imagemagick 6.9.7-4` installed from source with the following command:

```sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends

RUN cd /usr/local/src && \
    curl -L https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6/archive/6.9.7-4.tar.gz --output Imagick-6.9.7-4.tar.gz && \
    tar xvzf Imagick-6.9.7-4.tar.gz && \
    cd ImageMagick6-6.9.7-4 && \
    export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include && \
    export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib && \
    ./configure --with-module && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig /usr/local/lib && \
    cd .. && \
    rm -rf /usr/local/src/Imagick-6.9.7-4.tar.gz ImageMagick6-6.9.7-4
```

To convert the images I'm using the following function that works without any known problems at the moment

```php
<?php
public static function resize(string $src, string $dst, int $width, $height = false, int $quality = 90) : bool {
    if ($quality <= 0 || $quality > 100) {
        throw new \Exception(
            "quality is out of range. must be between 1 and 100. '".$quality."' given"
        );
    }

    // check if the source file exists
    if (!file_exists($src)) {
        throw new \Exception(
            "source file '".$src."' does not exist"
        );
    }

    // check if imagemagick is installed
    if (!extension_loaded("imagick") || !class_exists("Imagick")) {
        throw new \Exception(
            "Imagick Extension is not loaded"
        );
    }

    // create image
    $img = ImageHelpers::newImagick($src);

    // set backgroundcolor for transparent images and merge multiple layers to one
    $img->setBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel("#FFFFFF"));
    $img = $img->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);

    // auto orientation
    switch ($img->getImageOrientation()) {
        case \Imagick::ORIENTATION_BOTTOMRIGHT:
            $img->rotateimage("#000", 180); // rotate 180 degrees
            break;

        case \Imagick::ORIENTATION_RIGHTTOP:
            $img->rotateimage("#000", 90); // rotate 90 degrees CW
            break;

        case \Imagick::ORIENTATION_LEFTBOTTOM:
            $img->rotateimage("#000", -90); // rotate 90 degrees CCW
            break;
    }

    // set new orientation in exif-data
    $img->setImageOrientation(\Imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);

    // resizes to whichever is larger, width or height
    if ($height !== false) {
        $img->thumbnailImage($width, $height, true);
    } else {
        $img->cropThumbnailImage($width, $width);
    }

    // set iterator to 0 on PSD and XCF Files
    $ending = strtolower(substr($src, -3, 3));
    if (in_array($ending, [ "psd", "xcf" ])) {
        $img->setIteratorIndex(0);
    }

    // convert image to jpg
    $img->setImageFormat("jpg");

    // colorspace transformation
    // only if imagick version is not 6.9.10-23 (1690)
    // due to bug in imagick
    // imagick generates segfault
    $imagickVersion = \Imagick::getVersion();
    if ($imagickVersion['versionNumber'] ?? "" !== 1690) {
        try {
            // check if icc profiles exist
            $profiles = $img->getImageProfiles("*", false);
            $hasIccProfile = array_search("icc", $profiles) !== false;

            // fetch colorspace of the image
            $colorSpace = $img->getImageColorspace();

            // if images does not have an assigned profile and is cmyk add a default profile
            if ($hasIccProfile === false && $colorSpace == \Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK) {
                $img->profileImage("icc", file_get_contents(TB_PATH_ROOT."_common/icc/USWebUncoated.icc"));
            }

            // if images does not have an assigned profile and is srgb add a default profile
            if ($hasIccProfile === false && $colorSpace == \Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB) {
                $img->profileImage("icc", file_get_contents(TB_PATH_ROOT."_common/icc/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc"));
            }

            // set the new color profile
            $img->profileImage("icc", file_get_contents(TB_PATH_ROOT."_common/icc/AdobeRGB1998.icc"));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // do nothing
            // thumbnail creation will still work
        }
    }

    // set image compression
    $img->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    $img->setImageCompressionQuality($quality);

    // remove destination-file if already exists
    if (file_exists($dst) && unlink($dst) === false) {
        throw new \Exception(
            "destination file already exists but cannot be deleted"
        );
    }

    // write image
    $img->writeImage($dst);

    // clear image from memory
    $img->clear();

    // all done, image was created
    return true;
}
```

I do have the relevant icc files in the given folder, so they can be used to set the color profile.

Now as soon as I upgrade to Imagick 7 (7.0.10-43) I do have some images that are not converted correctly. I do have tiff images where the colors are inverted. Even if I remove the whole transformation-code this still happens.
Is there any known change in Imagmagick hat leads to those issues?
Or are there any tipps on where to search for the issue?

I broke this down as far as possible and this also happens with the following code:

```php
<?php
$src = __DIR__ . "/_common/_data/persistent/images/219.tif";
$dst = __DIR__ . "/output.jpg";

$img = new \Imagick($src);
$img->writeImage($dst);
```

This works in `Imagick 6.9.7-4` but not in `Imagick 7.0.10-43`. In 7 the whole image gets inverted.

The php imagick extension is installed from `pecl`

```sh
RUN pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick
```

Best regards, David

Comment: You should also post a snippet of simple code showing the problem so people can try it. It is very difficult for somebody to read and try your code as it is. Did you upgrade your imagemagick and Imagick version as they must match?

Comment: Hi Bonzo. Thanks for your reply. I broke this down as far as I could. I'm using this code for tests
`$img = new \Imagick($src); $img->writeImage($dst);`

This works in `Imagick 6.9.7-4` but not in `Imagick 7.0.10-43`. In 7 the whole image gets inverted.

I'm installing the php extension from `pecl`. Is there a better way to do this? To match the installed imagemagick version?
```bash
RUN pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick
```